# Wrong resolution on grub2?

Tags: grub2, resolution

My optimal screen resolution is 1600x900px, however when I first turn on my laptop, grub2 displays at 1024x768. I have an optimus system, so I am assuming that grub is using the intel card. When I do `vbeinfo` it says the maximum resolution is 1024x768, but the optimal resolution is 1600x900. I have tried adding `i915.modeset=1` to my grub config and changing `GRUB_GFXMODE` to `1600x900` but to no avail. All help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think that Grub doesn't support fancy high resolutions. It uses a fail-safe resolution. That way, if you spill coffee or something on your monitor, and you have to use a 'backup' monitor that only goes up to 1024X1280, it'll work, with a little margin of safety added, just incase. However, this is purely speculation. Do you really need to choose your OS in HD, though?

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee that GRUB will be able to use exactly the same resolution your Xserver is running at with your video hardware. The only way to find out what settings will be acceptable here is to use GRUB to tell you.
To find out, boot your computer and press your <kbd>C</kbd> key from your GRUB Menu to switch into [command-line mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Command_002dline-and-menu-entry-commands.html).

- To prevent text from scrolling up the screen uncontrollably, first use the command `set pager=1`.
- Then you can run the `vbeinfo` command for a list of resolutions your hardware can support.
- Write the numbers down on a piece of scrap paper if you need to.

Now, let see how you can change change GRUB menu resolution:

1. Open your `/etc/default/grub` file with a text editor and change your settings there: `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`.
2. Alter the numbers after where it says"`GRUB_GFXMODE=`" with a suitable resolution for your hardware.
3. Save the file before closing it.
4. Run `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` to write the changes to your `grub.cfg`.
5. Reboot and see if it worked.